# How do to restrict a html form input from being passed on form submission?

Tags: html, forms, post, form-submit

I have a simple registration form which has the fields : fname,lname, username, password and confirm password.
Upon submission, the form calls a servlet which processes the input.
How do I **block the confirm password field** from being passed over to the servlet post method?

Below is the snippet of the code:

HTML FORM SNAPSHOT:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<form name="UserRegistration" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/RegisterServlet" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
 <br>
Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
 <br>
Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username">
 <br>
Password:<br>
  <input type="text" name="password">
 <br>
Confirm Password:<br>
  <input type="text" name="cpassword">
 <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

I use confirm password input in the javascript form validation. after that step I have no use for it.

JAVASCRIPT CODE SNIPPET:

> ```
>  function validateForm() {
>       var fname = document.forms["UserRegistration"]["firstname"].value;
>       var lname = document.forms["UserRegistration"]["lastname"].value;
>       var uname = document.forms["UserRegistration"]["username"].value; 
>       var pass = document.forms["UserRegistration"]["password"].value; 
>       var cpass = document.forms["UserRegistration"]["cpassword"].value;
>
>       if(cpass == pass){
>       if (fname == null || fname == "" || lname == null || lname == "" || 
>               uname == null || uname == "" || pass == null || pass == "") {
>           alert("All fields must be filled out");
>           return false;
>       }else
>           {
>               return true;
>           }
>       }
>       else
>           {
>           alert("Passwords do not match")
>           return false
>           }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting the form you can remove the `name` attribute of the confirm password field , in that case this field will not be submitted:

```
if (fname == null || fname == "" || lname == null || lname == "" || 
          uname == null || uname == "" || pass == null || pass == "") {
      alert("All fields must be filled out");
      return false;
}else
{
    // remove the attribute name from element cpass
    cpass.removeAttribute('name');
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `disabled` attribute to `true` to prevent it from posting.

```
document.forms["UserRegistration"]["cpassword"].disabled = true;
```

Comment: AFAIK, enabling the "disabled" attribute, only disables user modification of the value in the text box. It will still be submitted as part of the form.

Comment: Disabled fields are not submitted. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Just allow cpassword's value to be transmitted to your servlet along with other information on the form. If your servlet determines that the password do not match, you can replay the form and ask the user to type the password and confirm it.

Do not rely only on JavaScript to do validation. Always perform server side validation. **<strike>If</strike> When** a user disables JavaScript in their browser and attempts to submit the form, or uses cURL or other means of `POST`ing the data to your servlet, they could send invalid data.

If you still want to just not send cpassword, you could use dotnetom's method or remove the element using something like this before doing `return true;`

```
(elem=document.getElementsByName("cpassword")[0]).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```